# Select count from different tables with a field in common

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

So here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT( tab1.id_z ) AS Count, tab_tot.name
FROM tab1 
INNER JOIN tab_id ON (tab1.id_key = tab_id.id_key) 
INNER JOIN tab_tot ON (tab_id.id_z = tab_tot.id_z) 
WHERE tab1.id_c = 10888 GROUP BY tab_id.id_z
```

In table tab_id there are 6 records with the same id_z but i receive 1 in Count.

How can I do?

Edit - this is my schema:

```
tab1
id_key | id_c 

tab_id
id_key |id_z

tab_tot
id_z | description
```

Though I have more records in tab_id, I "count" ever 1

Comment: can u share sample data of both the tables...

Comment: What `SELECT COUNT(id_z) FROM tab1;` does return ?

Comment: `GROUP BY` Gives yopu distinct id and you have 6 similar id so i guess it is a normal behaviour !!

Comment: Plz share sample data and table structure to help you..

Comment: The field you are using in GROUP BY is the same one in your COUNT, so you will always have only one `id_z`, as @Blood-HaZaRd pointed out.  I think you actually want to GROUP BY `tab_tot.name` instead - try that.

Comment: just replace count(tab1.id_z) with count(1)